# Pip3 trying to access folders that shouldn't exist

Tags: python, macos, pip, macos-sonoma

I am trying to install matplotlib because somehow all my python modules are missing and everything is gone wrong, so as normal I use `pip3 install matplotlib`, however this runs into an error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 806, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/private/var/folders/58/6kdshsgx3gj6k1pmsmst6fth0000gn/T/pip-target-5yt_jb8r/lib/python/packaging' -> '/Users/Bob/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/packaging'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 446, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 505, in _handle_target_dir
    shutil.move(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 822, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, copy_function=copy_function,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 557, in copytree
    return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 458, in _copytree
    os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=dirs_exist_ok)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/Bob/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/packaging'
```

I tried deleting python3 and reinstalling it with `brew uninstall python3` and `brew install python3` as I thought the python interpreter path was the issue, but no. I also deleted python from the Applications folder and reinstalled it from the website, but then again the same issue.

The issue is I don't understand why it is trying to access `/Users/Bob`, there is no user called Bob! If anything, it should be `/Users/childish`, I have tried using different methods such as `python3 -m pip install matplotlib` as well as using virtualenv but all of them lead to the same error.

I have also tried `pip3 install matplotlib --user` but this leads to a different error: `ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'` which is supposed to be mutually exclusive and should not occur at all, do I have to wipe my Mac and reinstall everything again, or could this be related to MacOs Sonoma beta? Anything would help!

Comment: You have not mentioned whether you are a Windows mac user or Ubuntu but if you are Ubuntu user then use sudo .

Comment: I have mentioned at the bottom I am a Mac user and have tagged it as well, I am running MacOS Sonoma beta version 14.1

Comment: Sorry. my bad .